# How to add additional information to datagridview , but dont show it

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, datagridview, datagrid

I have database which contains large amount of information about some jobs.
I want to show only two columns (name, and job number). But user can work with that jobs , select it delet it and i need to match all information from database with that datagrid. 
I came out with idea in which i would create list and match it with datagrid with id, and then manipulate with data.

Is there some easier approach ?

EDIT: To clear things up here is table example(Picture)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysGoz.png)

First column is job number, second is job name.

user is enable to select job from list , and then some textboxs are filled (date of creation,date of finish , job opener and lot of information which i dont want in datagridview) 

How to match that information?

Comment: Can you add a sample of what you expect and tables sample ? It's not really clear.

Comment: @Cesar i edited question

Answer (score 1):

You can load all needed information in your dataSet and show only the needed column in your datagridview.

To hide column from DataGridView use one of the following methods :

- Manually :

[image: Example 1]

- Using code :

[image: Example 2]